# Python Django manage.py shell Attribute error module 'ast' has no attribute 'AnnAssign'

Tags: django, python-3.x

So I'm working on this test app in Django and i wanted to add some data to my sql tables through the python shell. I ran the following command from the CMD

```
λ python manage.py shell
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 99, in handle
    return getattr(self, shell)(options)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 35, in ipython
    from IPython import start_ipython   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 109, in <module>
    _assign_nodes         = (ast.AugAssign, ast.AnnAssign, ast.Assign) AttributeError: module 'ast' has no attribute 'AnnAssign'
```

I'm using Python 3 and Django 2.0.3.

Some things I tried on my own:

I checked that ipython was up to date using pip, my database runs on SQL community server runs and works fine and the Django server itself also runs without issues.

EDIT: I did some more digging AST is part of the standard python library. However i dont find any issues with my python install, any ideas?

EDIT2: Tried reinstalling Ipython, same traceback error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so i did a complete reinstall of Django and Mysqlclient through PIP which solved the problem. I now have acess to the django shell.